# jQuery global ajax error handler fires before "local" one

Tags: jquery

I want to handle `401` errors globally and only deal with other errors locally.
Locally means inside the `fail` handler for an AJAX call.

To do that, I implemented an `ajaxError` handler on the `document`.
However, the problem is that the local `fail` handler is triggered before the global one.
So the `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` inside the global handler is useless.

How can I make it so that the global one is fired first and thus prevent the local one from firing at all.
Thank you.

Comment: you can't without wrapping all ajax requests in a helper method that instead bind the *"global"* error handler directly to the jqXHR and abandoning the global ajaxError handler. Even then i'm not sure if you can stop it from reaching the additional error handlers without even more work since these aren't technically events.

Comment: That's rather annoying. Why have a global handler if it fires after the local listener?... And it's too late for a wrapper.

Comment: Not necessarily too late. You could create a wrapper without actually changing the name of the method.

Comment: True, but it's simpler to just find the fail methods I need to suppress and include all their code in an if statement checking if the status is not 401 before executing anything. But that's a lousy way to do it.

Comment: have you considered using a statusCode callback instead? That could be assigned globally using ajaxSetup. I'm not entirely sure though if you could prevent the error callback from occurring since it's still a deferred object. It's either going to pass or fail. it can't just not do either.

Comment: I had until I read the `Its use is not recommended.` on the first line. But it's worth a shot seeing as I don't have many options. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't seen that line (still don't see it)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/ -> First line of text: `Description: Set default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is not recommended.`

Comment: Oh i thought you meant the statusCode option. In this case it's an option that you won't use anywhere else, therefore the risk of you overriding it is low.

Comment: That doesn't work, it fires before the local one. However, I did find a solution using beforeSend. However, it seems to only work when setting the error handler via `error` in AJAX settings. Haven't figured out a way to work with that when fail is used on the future returned by $.ajax.

Comment: according to the way deferred objects are built and how the $.ajax method is implemented, it shouldn't be possible to stop the .fail used directly on `$.ajax` unless you can get access to the deferred object rather than the promise object.

Comment: You can wrap the $.ajax function with some function like "makeAjaxCall" and in that function you can handle the 401 error otherwise call the local error handler, and use that function instead of $.ajax

Comment: I answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36313044/725957

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this solution, it is now possible to use jQuery's `$.ajaxPrefilter` function to intercept a specific error globally and prevent the `fail` handler for the AJAX call to be executed for that error. Simply need to replace the original `Deferred` object from the Ajax call with our own:

```js
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    options.error = $.noop();
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    jqXHR.done(dfd.resolve);
    jqXHR.fail(function () {
        if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
            // Handle the 401 error globally here
        } else {
            if (originalOptions.error) { dfd.fail(originalOptions.error); }
            dfd.rejectWith(jqXHR, Array.from(arguments));
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise(jqXHR);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    var statusCodeError = function(error) {
        throw new Error('--> Error code ' + error.status + ' on XMLHttpRequest');
    };
    var settings = {
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : '/ajax-script.php',
        dataType    : 'json',
        context     : document.body,
        statusCode  : {
            404: statusCodeError,
            301: statusCodeError,
            302: statusCodeError,
            401: statusCodeError,
            500: statusCodeError
        }, failure : statusCodeError
    };

    $.ajaxSetup(settings);
```